# Inserting stored procedure output into a new physical table with 2 additional columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Thanks for all your help.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, my requirement is I need to insert stored procedure output into a new table (not temp or virtual table) in database with 2 additional columns without values to be added.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Answer (score 0):

This is an example;

```
create procedure proc_1
as begin
    SELECT name, database_id FROM sys.databases
end;
go

create table new_tbl (
    name varchar(150),
    id int,
    new_col1 int,
    new_col2 int
)
go

declare @tab table(
    name varchar(150),
    id int  
)
begin
    insert into @tab
    exec proc_1

    insert into new_tbl
    select name, id, 1, 2 from @tab;
end;
go

select * from new_tbl

OutPut:
master  1   1   2
tempdb  2   1   2
model   3   1   2
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure which will give default columns as output.
for example:

```
CREATE Procedure proc1
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT name, database_id,1 as Col1,2 as Col2
    FROM sys.databases
END;
go
```

output of above SP will provide the 2 aditional columns needed.